# UIScrollView internal consistency crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm struggling with this intermittent crash issue on my UITableView which has UICollectionViews.

I have a navigation controller whose root view controller has:

1. UITableView with 3 sections
2. Each section has one row
3. Each row has a UICollectionView
4. The top row of UITableView (which is a collection view) is made to scroll automatically based on NSTimer.

The crash occurs when I push into the navigation controller and pop out back and forth. It happens when I do pushing and popping 3-4 times

The trace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38f74626 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                           0x312a6740 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 60
2   UIKit                           0x31020798 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 600
3   UIKit                           0x312a76b6 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 1394
4   UIKit                           0x310d33d2 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 414
5   UIKit                           0x310d322a -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:] + 26
6   UIKit                           0x310d31e2 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 26
7   UIKit                           0x31001952 -[UIView dealloc] + 374
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2e700140 CFRelease + 556
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e70b668 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 156
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38f79b66 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38f7a0ce (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2e70347c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2e798f0e __CFRunLoopRun + 1310
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2e703724 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2e703506 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
16  GraphicsServices                0x336726ce GSEventRunModal + 134
17  UIKit                           0x3106486c UIApplicationMain + 1132
18  BoatSenzeDev                    0x00110648 main (main.m:16)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x39468ab4 start + 0
```

Answer (score 26):

I think there's a bug somewhere on iOS 8 regarding the timing of `UITableViewController` (or plain `UIViewController` containing a `UITableView`) `dealloc` when dealing with transition animations. Somehow the view controller is already deallocated, but the table view is still trying to send messages to its **delegate**.

As a workaround, you can implement the `dealloc` method on the `UITableViewController` like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
}
```

Comment: This bug isn't just occuring in iOS8. I am getting Crashlytics reports on this from iOS8.1.3 and iOS7.1.2, iPad 2 and iPad Mini. But 90% iOS8 indeed. Because the exception doesn't throw on my device and my simulators, I need to wait for another App Store release to verify that this did indeed fix the error.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer why don't you Profile your app with instruments and check for zombies? Or you can run the app on your disconnected iPhone - make your app crash, then connect back, open Devices from Xcode, and you should be able to see the crash logs.

Comment: Thanks @IslamQ, i managed to reproduce the crash by heavy scrolling on the scrollview and then switch views quickly. My last update included the dealloc fix on all of my tableView view controllers and all related crashes have disappeared, including iOS7, 8, 8.1 and 8.2beta

Comment: Getting the same reports through Crashlytics (iOS7 & iOS8) but haven't been experiencing the crashes myself. I implemented this dealloc method, lets hope it'll fix it.

Comment: I'm getting them on newest iPod, but not on any iPhones.

Comment: Great answer! This solved our problems! Can s.o. file a radar and post the ID here? I'll duplicate it then.